# Tic tac toe evaluation error

Tags: c#, evaluation, tic-tac-toe, alpha-beta-pruning

I try to make tic-tac-toe with different board size and pieces to win.

I have evaluation function which depends on open paths. For example if we have

```
O--X
O---
--O
```

We get 10^2 ( for vertical first column ) + 10^1 (vertical second column) + 10^1 (for diagonal) + 10^1 (for horizontal 2nd row) + 10^1 (for last horizontal row).

To get the best best move I use function:

```
public Move FindBestMove(Board board, int depth, Game.Player currentTurn, Board.Piece currentPiece, Move move1 = null)
{
    if (depth <= 0 || board.AreEmptyPlaces() == false)
    {
        move1.Score = board.Score;

        if (_log)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + new String('\t', 4 - depth) +
                              string.Format("bestScore = {0}, player = {1}, status = {2}", board.Score,
                                            currentTurn, move1.EvaluateResult + "\n"));
        }

        return move1;
    }

    List<Move> allMoves = board.GetAllMoves(currentPiece);
    Move bestMove = null;

    foreach (Move move in allMoves)
    {
        Board newBoard = (Board)board.Clone();
        newBoard.MakeMove(move);

        Board newBoardForOpponent = (Board)board.Clone();
        Move moveForOppeonent = new Move { Piece = move.Piece == Board.Piece.O ? Board.Piece.X : Board.Piece.O, Position = move.Position, Score = move.Score };
        newBoardForOpponent.MakeMove(moveForOppeonent);

        IEvaluate evaluateOpenPathForOpponent = new EvaluateOpenPath(newBoardForOpponent.BoardSize, newBoardForOpponent.pieces, currentPiece == Board.Piece.O ? Board.Piece.X : Board.Piece.O, newBoardForOpponent.ToWin);
        IEvaluate evaluateOpenPath = new EvaluateOpenPath(newBoard.BoardSize, newBoard.pieces, currentPiece, newBoard.ToWin);

        EvaluateResult opponentResult = evaluateOpenPathForOpponent.EvaluateOpponent();
        EvaluateResult playerResult = evaluateOpenPath.Evaluate();

        if (currentTurn == Game.Player.Computer)
        {
            newBoard.Score += (playerResult.Score) + (opponentResult.Status == EvaluateResult.EvaluateStatus.Won ? opponentResult.Score : 0);
        }
        else
        {
            newBoard.Score += (playerResult.Score) + (opponentResult.Status == EvaluateResult.EvaluateStatus.Lost ? opponentResult.Score : 0);
        }

        if (currentTurn == Game.Player.Computer && (_initialDepth == depth || _initialDepth - 1 == depth) &&
            //(playerResult.Score == 0 && opponentResult.Score == 0) &&
                   (opponentResult.Status == EvaluateResult.EvaluateStatus.Lost ||
                    playerResult.Status == EvaluateResult.EvaluateStatus.Won))
        {
            //bestMove = BestMoveChagneStatus(bestMove, move, playerResult, opponentResult);
            bestMove = BestMoveChagneStatus(bestMove, move, playerResult, opponentResult);
            bestMove.Source = Move.SourceEnum.LostOrWon;
            break;
        }

        if (_log)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                new String('\t', 4 - depth) +
                "gracz = {1}, pozycja = {2},wynik = {0}, glebokosc = {3}, status = {4}, (bestmove = {5})",
                newBoard.Score, move.Piece, move.Position, depth, move.EvaluateResult, bestMove);
        }

        Move findBestMove = FindBestMove(newBoard, depth - 1, (currentTurn == Game.Player.Computer ? Game.Player.Human : Game.Player.Computer), (currentPiece == Board.Piece.O ? Board.Piece.X : Board.Piece.O), move);
        if (findBestMove != null)
        {
            if (bestMove == null)
            {
                bestMove = findBestMove;
            }
            else
            {
                if (currentTurn == Game.Player.Computer &&
                    //(playerResult.Score == 0 && opponentResult.Score == 0) &&
                           (opponentResult.Status == EvaluateResult.EvaluateStatus.Lost ||
                            playerResult.Status == EvaluateResult.EvaluateStatus.Won))
                {
                    //bestMove = BestMoveChagneStatus(bestMove, move, playerResult, opponentResult);
                    bestMove = BestMoveChagneStatus(bestMove, move, playerResult, opponentResult);
                    bestMove.Source = Move.SourceEnum.LostOrWon;
                    break;
                }

                if (bestMove.EvaluateResult == EvaluateResult.EvaluateStatus.None && findBestMove.EvaluateResult != EvaluateResult.EvaluateStatus.None)
                {
                    bestMove = BestMoveChagneStatus(bestMove, findBestMove, playerResult, opponentResult);
                    bestMove.Source = Move.SourceEnum.Status;
                }
                else if (bestMove.EvaluateResult == EvaluateResult.EvaluateStatus.Lost &&
                         findBestMove.EvaluateResult == EvaluateResult.EvaluateStatus.Won)
                {
                    bestMove = BestMoveChagneStatus(bestMove, findBestMove, playerResult, opponentResult);
                    bestMove.Source = Move.SourceEnum.Status;
                }
                else if (findBestMove.Score > bestMove.Score && findBestMove.EvaluateResult == EvaluateResult.EvaluateStatus.Won)
                {
                    bestMove = BestMoveChagneStatus(bestMove, findBestMove, playerResult, opponentResult);
                    bestMove.Source = Move.SourceEnum.Score;
                }
                else if (findBestMove.Score == bestMove.Score && Random.NextDouble() > 0.00 && findBestMove.EvaluateResult == EvaluateResult.EvaluateStatus.Won)
                {
                    bestMove = BestMoveChagneStatus(bestMove, findBestMove, playerResult, opponentResult);
                    bestMove.Source = Move.SourceEnum.Score;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return bestMove;

}

private static Move BestMoveChagneStatus(Move bestMove, Move move, EvaluateResult playerResult,
                                         EvaluateResult opponentResult)
{
    bestMove = move;
    if (playerResult.Status != EvaluateResult.EvaluateStatus.None)
    {
        bestMove.EvaluateResult = playerResult.Status;
    }
    else if (opponentResult.Status != EvaluateResult.EvaluateStatus.None)
    {
        bestMove.EvaluateResult = opponentResult.Status;
    }
    else
    {
        bestMove.EvaluateResult = EvaluateResult.EvaluateStatus.None;
    }
    return bestMove;
}
```

Program find move, but it isn't always the best. Especially he dd not see moves when opponent has 2 wining chances. Moreover when algorithm has wining move, he first will block opponent. For example:

```
XO-
XO-
---
```

If computer is an O, he will block X first, but it shouldn't.

Can you please tell me what can I improve in this function ? Maybe there is error which I do not see :( Evaluation function works fine I wrote unit test for test it.

Comment: You may want to have a look at typical game algorithms for these types of problems: negamax and alpha/beta pruning in particular.

Comment: It seems that you've gone a bit overboard with the OOP. Try simplifying your code to make it a bit more understandable.

Comment: This is extremely verbose...as Jared said the OOP may be getting in the way. I mean, I tried to help debug your code but there's so much apparent redundancy...